# CiviMail - How to include an Image in a Header

Tags: civimail

If I want to include an image in a mail, I have the WYSYWYG CKEditor which enables me to do that.

But how can I include an Image in a CiviMail Header ?

Answer (score 5):

In the headers and the footers you don not have the convenience of a WYSYWYG editor. So you have to write HTML. An example of including the logo in the footer is:

```
 <br/>
 <img src='https://<site>/sites/default/files/logosite.png'/>
```

However you can create an example mail in de WYSYWYG editor and then use the *Source* button to examine the generated HTML code. Use this as an example and copy the relevant code bits.